# Capturing user data for machine learning and recommendations

Tags: php, cookies, machine-learning, session-cookies, recommendation-engine

I am in an infrastructure guy so forgive if the question sounds naive. I need to work with a dev partner in capturing the following data from a PHP web application.

- Time of entry
- Device, OS, Browser
- Network, source of the visit
- User actions on site, speed of scroll
- Current page the user is on

The idea is to pump all this data to a data store to run machine learning algorithms to come up with near real-time recommendations.  I would like to understand to what extend does a standard cookie can track this data. Is it possible to collect all of this data?

What is the right way to go about collecting this data?

Comment: Some of this stuff is less complicated than others but I think you may need to use a database for a lot of this to store the data for analysis.

Comment: @Rasclatt Yes, I am clear about the storing data part. We are planning to push this data to a NoSQL data store. It is the process of capturing this data itself is what I am not clear about.

Comment: Well for time of entry, you just record new IPs that hit your site with a timestamp, the device and all that can be captured using the `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] `, actions on the site would be derived from recording IPs as they go through each page, javascript could capture clicks on items and probably scrolling, current page would be part of the recording of IPs per page with timestamp. Just some ideas....

Answer (score 1):

Everything about the user can be stored in a `database` for future reviews which is the best way to keep a track of user on what he does on the website.

To give a few ideas,

> 1) Time of entry ==> When the user enters the website just, having a
>   `TIME_STAMP` field will do the trick, which will automatically update
>   the user's entry value.
>
> 2) For detecting OS =>  just use `var_dump(PHP_OS);`
>
> 3) For detecting browser,device => `$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];` will
>   do the trick
>
> 4) Current page the user is on =>  This can be stored in a `$_SESSION`
>   variable and it can be kept updating every time the user goes to some
>   other page and store that too in the `database`
>
> 5) UserActions => Depends on what actions you want to capture and the
>   same can be updated in the database as well.